# ASP.NET MVC - Set Master View accordingly with Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

By any chance, is there any easy way to set a default MasterView for all the actions inside a specific controller?

For example If I have the **HomeController** I want all the actions inside it to inherit the **Site.Master** as default, but If I am inside **AccountsController** I want all the action to inherit the **Admin.Master** and so on..

I managed to do it with:

```
return View("viewName", "masterName", objectModel);
```

But by doing this I have to apply it every time I call the View method.

I was looking for something simpler like on rails where we can declare:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  layout 'site'

   def index
   end

   def create
   ...

end

class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  layout 'admin'

  def index
  end

  def create
  ...  

end
```

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could override OnActionExecuting in that Controller class.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
{ 
    ViewData["MasterfileToUser"] = "site";
}
```

Or if you like you can turn this into an ActionFilterAttribute you can apply on the controller or action level

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class MasterFileFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Master { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext)   
    {        
            if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
                    ((ViewResult)filterContext.Result).MasterName = Master;
    }
}
```

which you then in turn use like so:

```
[MasterFileFilterAttribute(Master = "site")] 
public class HomeController : Controller 
{ 
    // Action methods 
}
```

Comment: Hi Olle, thanks for your answer. Just One thing that I didn't catch, is how a ViewData["MasterfileToUser"] reflects the Master file? Is that anything else that I should do to make it load the Master File Properly?

Comment: My bad assigning it from viewdata won't work. I took a second stab but I am currently not somewhere where I can test this. In OnActionExecuted the result (a ViewResult instance) is available it has a Masterpage property so I am now assigning it there. Please test yourself :)

Comment: Olle Just one think here...
Now Everytime I call the method RedirectToAction it throws an error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'.
And acuses the MasterFileFileAttribute class. Any ideas on how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Hy Olle, I found the answer! :)
I'm very new with this C# thing so there's a lot of things that I don't know how to do (like 'unless' from ruby (didn't worked with (!...)) but it worked using the following code over your class: http://pastebin.com/mf6d587e
I found some direction to this at: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx
Feel free to update your answer with a revised code if you want.
Thanks again

Comment: Yeah some error checking might come in handy. I slightly changed it to check if it is a ViewResult instead of checking if it isn't a RedirectResult since there will be more result types it wpn't work on like a JsonResult or a BinaryResult etc... And the unless you woulld do with if (!(filterContext.Result is RedirectResult) && !(filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)) {} in your example.

Comment: That's perfect Olle. So I think the question is answered!
Thanks a lot for you help! All the best

Comment: If assigning it via ViewData never works, you have forgot to update or remove your answer's first code snippet.